# Efficient implementation of bfs algorithm for a subgraph of a complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, complement

I'm stuck in the following problem:

I have the adjacency lists of a subgraph which is part of a complete graph. What I want to do is to apply bfs algorithm to the complement of the given subgraph. So, to do that, I need the succesors of each vertex in the complement.

What is the most efficient way to do that? The graph has a huge number of vertices and edges (~1 000 000).

Comment: Is it [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23030181/1127872) again?

Comment: If you want to perform seaching in the complement, why not generating the successors in the complement on the fly by following every non-edge?

Comment: Problem solved. It worked as Codor said. Thanks!