# Best way to traverse an almost complete undirected weighted graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

need help with an optimized solution for the following problem http://acm.ro/prob/probleme/B.pdf.

Depending on the cost i either traverse the graph using only new edges, or using only
old edges, both of them work, but i need to pass test in a limited number of milliseconds,
and the algorithm for the old edges is dragging me down.

I need a way to optimize this, any suggestions are welcome

EDIT: for safety reasons i am taking the algorithm down, i'm sorry, i'm new so I don't
know what i need to do to delete the post now that it has answers

Comment: Hello! Questions like this are better asked at [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is u[]?  What is q?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complete graph with only two possible costs. What's the shortest path's cost from 0 to N - 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030181/complete-graph-with-only-two-possible-costs-whats-the-shortest-paths-cost-fro)

Comment: This is the third time I see this problem on SO. What's the deal? :) Anyways, I got accepted with my segment tree approach, and it's pretty short and general

Answer (score 1):

My initial algorithmic suggestion relied on an incorrect reading of the problem.  Further, a textbook breadth-first search or Dijkstra on a graph of this size is unlikely to finish in a reasonable amount of time.  There's likely an early-termination trick that you can employ for large cases; the thread Niklas B. linked to suggests several (as well as some other approaches).  I couldn't find an early-termination trick that I could prove worked.

These micro-optimisation notes are still relevant, however:

I'd suggest **not** using Java's built-in `Queue` container for this (or any other built-in Java containers for anything else in a programming contest).  It turns your 4-byte `int` into a gargantual `Integer` structure.  This is very probably where your blowup is coming from.  You can use a 500000-long `int[]` to store the data in your queue and two ints for the front and back of the queue instead.  In general, you want to avoid instantiating `Object`s in Java contest programming because of their overhead.

Likewise, I'd suggest representing the edges of the graph as either a single big `int[]` or a 500000-long `int[][]` to cut down on that piece of overhead.

Comment: The problem statement says "Each of the new trains replaces an old one", so I think you *do* have to BFS the old-train routes too.

Comment: j_random_hacker is right, you can use the old edges, they just have a different cost

Comment: I don't think that's the solution, i'm sorry i forgot to mention this, in some tests you have around ~300000 nodes, that are initially all connected to each other, then some of them get replaced (or rather the cost between two edges does), i think the best way is to traverse only the new edges, because there are fewer of those...

Comment: i'm trying to do as @tmyklebu said, and it works with a small matrix, like [100][100], but when I try to make a [100000+][100000+], it crashes,it gives me an out of memory error, any ideas ?

Comment: @user2288240: Don't explicitly form the old-train edges.  BFS only on the new-train edges.  I'll update the first paragraph of my answer to an algorithm that works shortly; I initially misread the problem to have new trains running alongside the old trains.

Answer (score 0):

I only saw one queue in you code. That means you are searching from one direction only.

You may want to take a look at

[Bidirectional Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search)

Comment: It says: "Bidirectional search is a graph search algorithm that finds a shortest path from an initial vertex to a goal vertex in a directed graph.", this is an undirected graph, not sure this applies for it.

Comment: You could imagine that an undirected graph is a directed graph (both way). The improvement is exponential. If you assume average degree is k, distance is L. Then one way search is roughly k^L, while two way search is roughly 2 * K^(L/2)

Comment: and how would i implement it ? using 2 queues ? the second one i initialize with N (the last node) then while(!queue.isEmpty() && !newqueue.isEmpty()) then i poll one element out of every list, and this is were it gets a bit fuzzy, do you know a good pseucode i can follow, or an existing code ?

Comment: Bidirectional search in a graph with 500000^2 edges will still be too slow (the shortest paths can have length > 5 if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: you are probably right Niklas B, if this solution only halves the time, it's still not enough, but i am still willing to try it once i find a decent enough implementation of it...

Comment: @user2288240 It's definitely an interesting algorithm, so it can't hurt to learn it, but for this problem it makes no sense. Have a look at the other thread where there are multiple good answers. May I ask where the recent interest for this particular problem comes from? Is this reused in some other contest?

Comment: @NiklasB. for a personal assignment, and it's very frustrating because when i tested it locally it gave me a decent enough time, but on the platform that i need to upload it to, it's way higher, so the fact of the matter is that this algorithm work, i just need a way to improve it, can i add some sort of heuristic ? I'm not very sure how that works

Comment: I bet you can prove that a meet-in-the-middle Dijkstra variant works here, actually.